# como fazer upload de um aquivo e baixa-lo atraves do php?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

eu criei um botão para fazer o ulpoad de um arquivo para o banco de dados. ate ai beleza. mas tem um problema ele salva o arquivo com o dia e a hora, em vez do nome do arquivo. queria saber se existe um meio de salvar esse arquivo com o próprio nome ou modifica-lo antes de fazer o upload. e gostaria de saber como faço para baixa-lo de novo, exemplo: eu fiz um upload de uma consulta medica, e na próxima consulta gostaria de baixa-la.

```
    <?phpif(isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])){
  date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

  $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
  $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
  $dir = 'uploads/'; //Diretório para uploads

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo}?>


        <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer buscar o nome, você tem o código errado.

```
$new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext;
```

Nesta linha acima mostrada, você dá o nome do ficheiro com a data e hora do sistema. Para pôr o nome certo, recomendo usar o seguinte código

```
$new_name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];
```

Deste modo, irá buscar o nome original e a sua extenção, deixando a variável `$ext` inútil.

Agora para fazer download, se o ficheiro for uma imagem, basta indicar o caminho dessa imagem num `<a>`, assim

```
<a href="seusite/imagens/suaimagem.jpg" download>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Deste modo conseguirá transferir a imagem.

Link da propriedade do [download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).